# Heat transport from electrons in Drude model

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, states-of-matter

In Drude model we calculate the heat current supposing that electrons coming from low temperature side carry less energy than electron who have made their last collision on higher temperature side, i.e. if $T(x)$ is crescent, $\varepsilon(T(x-l)) > \varepsilon(T(x+l))$. Then we say that due to the Seebeck effect average electron velocity is actually the same everywhere. So if $v_T$ is the thermal velocity after the last collision we need also to take into account that in steady-state we have a field $\vec{E}$ such that $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}mv_T^2-qE=\frac{1}{2}m\bar{v}^2$ with $\frac{1}{2}mv_T^2=\frac{3}{2}k_bT$ while $\bar{v}$ is constant everywhere. If $\varepsilon$ is costant everywhere due to the Seebeck effect, how can be $\varepsilon(T(x-l)) > \varepsilon(T(x+l))$?